# How to remove extra blank space from Menu

Tags: android, user-interface, android-menu

[image]I am new in Android and using Overflow Menu in my program,

I need to know few things:

**Question 1:** How to remove extra blank space in Options, like in : Video, Email

**Question 2:** Want to hide both Activity Name or Application Name and ICON from FirstActivity

View my code below,

**Menu** > *items.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:title="@string/phone"
        android:icon="@drawable/phone"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"        
    />

    <item 
        android:id="@+id/computer"
        android:title="@string/computer"
        android:icon="@drawable/computer"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"        
    />

    <item 
        android:id="@+id/gamepad"
        android:title="@string/gamepad"
        android:icon="@drawable/gamepad"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"        
    />

    <item 
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:title="@string/camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/camera"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"        
    />

    <item 
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:title="@string/video"
        android:icon="@drawable/video"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"        
    />

    <item 
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:title="@string/email"
        android:icon="@drawable/email"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"        
    />

</menu>
```

*Manifest.xml:*

```
 <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
        android:allowBackup="true" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.sample.menu.HomeActivity"
            android:label="Demo App"                        
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.sample.menu.FirstActivity"
            android:label="First Activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.sample.menu.second" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>     

    </application>
```

*FirstActivity.java:*

```
 public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);        
        getOverflowMenu();
    }
```

Comment: set width of video and email to wrapcontent

Comment: You could always give an android:layout_width attribute in dp. You could also try out wrap_content. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: @Akshay not getting option width in item menu

Comment: post code from layout file..xml

Comment: @Niko in items.xml not getting width option

Comment: @Sonali DO YOU FIND ANY SOLUTION.

Answer (score 0):

for your Question 2:
   in onCreate()

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

this is to make action bar icon transparent

```
getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
```

in Manifest.xml

```
<android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

For your Question 1:

[this link is useful for you](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173121/Android-Menus-My-Way)

Comment: i just want to remove name and icon, i mean my back button will remain there as it is

Answer (score 0):

For question 2 add

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Right before :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
```

Comment: i just want to remove name and icon, once i will use above line, then it will also remove back button functionality from my program, and this will also effect on UI like still i am showing options at bottom but after that change my option will come only after pressing menu button

Comment: Who says it will harm your back button functionality and UI? Its not ture!

Answer (score 0):

**To Full Screen use,**

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
```

FOR OVERFLOW MENU, please elaborate more What u want..?